# When multiple clicks on activity navigation click, why 2nd activity lifecycle methods calling double times

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

When i multiple taps on a activity passing button, it takes `activity1` has been pause state and after a few seconds `activity2` has been come to foreground/visible to the user state.

my problem is , when we are moving on activities with multiple taps, it takes few seconds to user has been wait for next activity come to the visible state. it's really a bad practice.

Here is Call Logs of acticity lifecycle methods:

```
calling pause - Activity1

call: calling noti create  - Activity2
call: calling noti start - Activity2
call: calling noti resume- Activity2
call: calling noti pause- Activity2
//2nd time calls of lifecycle methods
calling noti create- Activity2
call: calling noti start- Activity2
call: calling noti resume- Activity2
```

Here is Button click of activity navigation:

```
@OnClick({R.id.card_notification})
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.card_notification:
                 startActivity(new Intent(context, NotificationsActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

              break;
        }
    }
```

if i remove `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`, `activity2` opens multiple times when multiple taps on button click.

I tried with set launch mode in the manifest file.

```
<activity android:launchMode=”singleTop” />
```

in this case also `activity 2` takes few mill seconds to come to visible state.

*Note: When single tap/click everything works fine.*

Please help me, what's going wrong in this scenario.

Here 2nd activity code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_noti_detail);
        Log.e("call", "noti create");

        context = this;
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setToolbar();
        callApi("");
        etSearchh.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) ->
        {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                isSearch = true;
                //membersList = null;
                callApi(etSearchh.getText().toString().trim());
                CommonUtils.hideKeyboard(this);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        etSearchh.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
                    iv_clearSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    iv_clearSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        iv_clearSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                iv_clearSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                etSearchh.setText("");
                //membersList = null;
                callApi("");
            }
        });

    }

    private void callApi(String searchBy) {
        new NotificationController(apiCallBack, context, searchBy).callTokenAPI();
    }

    private void setToolbar() {
        toolbarTitle.setText(MyApplication.getLabelModel().getLabels().getTT_NOTIFICATIONS());
        etSearchh.setHint(MyApplication.getLabelModel().getLabels().getSEARCH_NOTIFICATION());
    }

    private void setRecycler(List<Notifications> notifications) {
        mAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(notifications, context);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.iv_back)
    public void onViewClicked() {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.e("Call", "calling noti start");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.e("Call", "calling noti resume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.e("Call", "calling noti stop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e("Call", "calling noti pause");
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent multiple executions of button presses, you need to add a `boolean` variable that you use to remember that the button has been clicked and ignore the button click as "noise" if you see it again. Using your example, do this:

Add a `boolean` member variable to your class:

```
private boolean buttonClicked;
```

In `onViewClicked()` method, set the variable `buttonClicked` and ignore the click if it was already set:

```
public void onViewClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.card_notification:
             // Ignore if already clicked
             if (buttonClicked) {
                 return;
             }
             startActivity(new Intent(context, NotificationsActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
             // Remember that the button was clicked
             buttonClicked = true;
             break;
     }
```

This will prevent multiple clicks from starting multiple copies of `NotificationsActivity`. When the user returns to this `Activity`, you will want to reset `buttonClicked` in `onResume()` so that the user can again click the button (otherwise the user will only be able to click the button once!).

Comment: Thanks @David, in this case multiple clicks handling fine, but when click on multiple times on a button app goes to recent apps and remains same until i touch the app only comes to foreground.

Comment: Sorry this makes no sense. Please explain better.

Comment: call: calling pause - Activity1  ****
call: calling noti create  - Activity2 ****
call: calling noti resume - Activity2  ****
call: calling noti pause - Activity2 ****
call: calling noti Stop- Activity1 ****
call: calling noti Stop- Activity2 ****

Comment: I don't know why Activity2 is stopping. You'll need to look at your code in Activity2 to see what would be causing it to stop. Why is your app going to the background? Are you starting another app or another Activity in your app? Are you putting your app in the background?

Comment: i'm  just staring another activity only.. i'm really annoying, why it is stopped the 2nd activity.

Comment: Well, you must be doing something else. Post the code that is executed in `Activity2` in `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()`.

Comment: can you please look above at updated question with 2nd activity code including life cycle methods.